# Converting icefaces 1.8 Project to Icefaces 3.0

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces, jsf-1.2, icefaces-3, icefaces-1.8

I have a Project build in icefaces 1.8/ JSF1.2 and I need it to convert to icefaces 3.0. This is the first time I am doing this conversion process and facing lots of difficulties. I am very new to Icefaces(Infact I have touched it 15 days back for the first time) so pardon me if I ask any silly questions.

With the help of many JAVA forums I made some changes in the project but now stuck at one point very badly. I will note down the changes I have done so far.
    (1) Have converted all JSP files to XHTML files.
    (2) Have made changes in Faces-config.
    (3) Have changed the web.xml(although I am getting many errors here).
    (4) Changing the jar files(This is the most difficult part). I am not able to get the right jars and I am struggling with this issue for past 4-5 days.

Here I will post the web.xml(both for original and modified project),and the jar file list for the original project. Kindly help me out in the correct changing of the jar files and modification of web.xml because these are the two parts where I am getting stuck.

***Web.xml(Original project on icefaces 1.8)***

```
    xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
    web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"

        <context-param>
            <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.concurrentDOMViews</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.debugDOMUpdate</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.faces.verifyObjects</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
            <param-value>4048576</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
            <param-value>server</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.standardRequestScope</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.synchronousUpdate</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <filter>
            <filter-name>UploadFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <description>The maximum allowed upload size in bytes.  If this is set to a negative value, there is no maximum.  The default value is 1000000.</description>
                <param-name>maxSize</param-name>
                <param-value>1000000</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <description>The size (in bytes) of an uploaded file which, if it is exceeded, will cause the file to be written directly to disk instead of stored in memory.  Files smaller than or equal to this size will be stored in memory.  The default value is 4096.</description>
                <param-name>sizeThreshold</param-name>
                <param-value>4096</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>UploadFilter</filter-name>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        </filter-mapping>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.servlet.LifecycleListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.PersistentFacesServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.component.inputfile.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>ExceptionHandlerServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.sun.errorhandler.ExceptionHandler</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>errorHost</param-name>
                <param-value>localhost</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>errorPort</param-name>
                <param-value>24444</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </servlet>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>ThemeServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.sun.webui.theme.ThemeServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.iface</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/block/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/uploadHtml</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>ExceptionHandlerServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/error/ExceptionHandler</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>ThemeServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/theme/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>Main.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
        <error-page>
            <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
            <location>/error/ExceptionHandler</location>
        </error-page>
        <error-page>
            <exception-type>java.io.IOException</exception-type>
            <location>/error/ExceptionHandler</location>
        </error-page>
        <error-page>
            <exception-type>javax.faces.FacesException</exception-type>
            <location>/error/ExceptionHandler</location>
        </error-page>
        <error-page>
            <exception-type>com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.ApplicationException</exception-type>
            <location>/error/ExceptionHandler</location>
        </error-page>
        <jsp-config>
            <jsp-property-group>
                <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
                <is-xml>true</is-xml>
            </jsp-property-group>
            </jsp-config>

        <resource-ref>
            <description>DataSource Reference</description>
            <res-ref-name>jdbc/Project_name_MySQL</res-ref-name>
            <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        </resource-ref>
        </web-app>
```

***web.xml(after changing)***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.debugDOMUpdate</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.verifyObjects</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>-1</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/icefaces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ExceptionHandlerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.errorhandler.ExceptionHandler</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>errorHost</param-name>
            <param-value>localhost</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>errorPort</param-name>
            <param-value>24444</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ThemeServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.webui.theme.ThemeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>



    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ExceptionHandlerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/error/ExceptionHandler</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ThemeServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/theme/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Main.jsf</welcome-file>

        </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
        <location>/error/ExceptionHandler</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.io.IOException</exception-type>
        <location>/error/ExceptionHandler</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.FacesException</exception-type>
        <location>/error/ExceptionHandler</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.ApplicationException</exception-type>
        <location>/error/ExceptionHandler</location>
    </error-page>


    <resource-ref>
        <description>DataSource Reference</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/property_manager_MySQL</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
    </web-app>
```

***jar file userd in original project is***

```
(1)appbase.jar
(2) backport-util-concurrent-2.2_1.jar
(3)commons-beanutils.jar
(4) commons-collections.jar
(5)commons-digester.jar
(6)commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
(7)commons-logging.jar
(8)dataprovider-1.0.jar
(9)icefaces-1.8.2.jar
(10)icefaces-bm.jar
(11)icefaces-comps-1.8.2.jar
(12)jsf-api.jar
(13)jsfcl.jar
(14)jsf-impl.jar
(15)json-2.0.jar
(16)jstl.jar
(17)mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar
(18)sqlx.jar
(19)standard.jar
(20)webui-jsf-4.4.0.1.jar
```

***Jar file added in modieied project***

```
(1)appbase.jar
(2)backport-util-concurrent-2.2_1.jar
(3)commons-beanutils.jar
(4)commons-collections.jar
(5)commons-digester.jar
(6)commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
(7)commons-logging.jar
(8)dataprovider-1.0.jar
(9)icefaces.jar
(10)icefaces-ace-2.0.0.jar
(11)icefaces-compat.jar
(12)javax.faces.jar
(13)jsf-api-2.1.3.jar
(14)jsfcl.jar
(15)jsf-facelets.jar
(16)jsf-impl-2.1.3.jar
(17)json-2.0.jar
(18)jstl.jar
(19)jxl.jar
(20)krysalis-jCharts-1.0.0-alpha-1.jar
(21)mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar
(22)sqlx.jar
(23)standard.jar
(24)webui-jsf-4.4.0.1.jar
```

guys after removing icefaces-bm.jar and icefaces-comps-1.8.2.jar I am facing lot of issue because I am using InputFile functionality in my project and dont know how to change it. I am using icefaces-ace-2.0.0.jar for FileUpload feature but its not of much help till now.As for icefaces-bm.jar, I have nt found any alternative yet. Please help me out with the correct collections of JAR files.

Errors I am getting while running the program:-

```
Oct 17, 2013 11:36:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet uploadServlet as unavailable
Oct 17, 2013 11:36:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.icefaces.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1585)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Oct 17, 2013 11:36:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Oct 17, 2013 11:36:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Oct 17, 2013 11:36:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@2ce5a2')
Oct 17, 2013 11:36:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet uploadServlet as unavailable
Oct 17, 2013 11:36:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.icefaces.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:530)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1471)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:792)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1436)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:856)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:353)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Oct 17, 2013 11:50:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Oct 17, 2013 11:50:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
Oct 17, 2013 11:51:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Oct 17, 2013 11:51:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Oct 17, 2013 11:51:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@19cc8fd')
Oct 17, 2013 12:01:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Oct 17, 2013 12:01:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
Oct 17, 2013 12:04:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Oct 17, 2013 12:04:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Oct 17, 2013 12:04:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@12d5c20')
Oct 17, 2013 12:21:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Oct 17, 2013 12:21:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
Oct 17, 2013 12:22:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Oct 17, 2013 12:22:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Oct 17, 2013 12:22:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@1e820d7')
Oct 17, 2013 12:29:26 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession writeObject
WARNING: Cannot serialize session attribute com.sun.faces.application.view.activeViewMaps for session B8DA4BD3A0286DE0B3FCA8A7A903EA86
java.io.NotSerializableException: apppropertymanagerface.controller.Page1
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1671)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1077)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stopInternal(StandardManager.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5462)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1582)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you check out the updated version of the migration docs: http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/ICEfaces+1.x+Compatibility

First off, do you know where icefaces-bm.jar came from? I'm not familiar with that. So until you know what it is, I would leave it out. Also please list any exceptions that you're seeing on startup (I assume that the app isn't starting up at all?). And it's best to upgrade to the latest ICEfaces 3.3.0 version, including the included JSF version 2.1.19.

You can remove the following context-parameters as they're no longer used in ICEfaces 3:

- com.icesoft.faces.concurrentDOMViews
- com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility
- com.icesoft.faces.standardRequestScope
- com.icesoft.faces.synchronousUpdate

Remove the Persistent Faces Servlet and it's servlet mappings.

Your welcome-file should be 'Main.jsf' not 'Main.xhtml'.

I'm not sure about the compatibility of the old Sun Rave framework on JSF 2. It might be best if you started again with the ICEfaces Showcase sample war/project from the ICEfaces 3.3.0 bundle. Just add your xhtml pages and java classes. Remove all of your Sun Rave dependencies from the pages.

As for the File Upload, have you seen the tutorial and docs for the Ace FileEntry?

http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/FileEntry

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: Actually earlier it was not running at all but thanks to your guidance its running now. However I am getting hell lot of errors in this. Here I will put the error I am getting. But first I will put this that since I was getting error in file upload so I removed all reference of file upload from the programs and even deleted the jar files but its still giving me the error that it was giving before about file upload..its strange why its still giving me error when there is no reference to any file upload or jar file in the program.

Comment: Anyways I am putting the error I am getting in the edited question as I was not able to put it here due to word_count limitation. I have edited the web.xml file as well in the question.

Comment: If you can't post the errors here, please feel free to post them on the ICEfaces forum, and we can follow it up there.

Comment: I will post the error on the iceface forum, but I have already posted the error here, please look at the question segment. I have posted the error there. Thanks

Comment: Try removing the commons-file-upload-1.2.2.jar. I believe that is now wrapped by the Ace component class org.icefaces.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.